# Confused about proof that $\log(n!) = \theta(n\log n)$

Tags: proof-verification, logarithms

So I was able to show that:

$\log(n!) = O(n \log n)$ without any problems.

My question is when trying to prove that $\log (n!) = \Omega(n \log n)$.

I was able to show that:

\begin{align}
\log(n!) & = \log(1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots n) \\
& = \log(1) + \log(2) + \log(3) + \dots + \log(n) \\  
& = \log(1) + \dots + \log\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + \dots + \log(n) \\  
& \geq \log\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+ \log\left(\frac{n}{2} + 1\right) + \dots + \log(n)
\end{align}

(ie, the larger half of the sum)

*Note: this is the part I don't fully understand*

\begin{align}
& \geq \log\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + \log\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + \cdots + \log\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) & & \text{(add them $n/2$ times)} \\
& = \log \left(\frac{n}{2} \cdot \frac{n}{2} \cdots \frac{n}{2}\right) & & \left(\frac{n}{2} \text{times}\right) \\
& = \log \left( \frac{n}{2}^{\frac{n}{2}} \right) \\  
& = \frac{n}{2} \log \left(\frac{n}{2}\right) & & \text{(by log exponent rule)}
\end{align}

Thus,

$\log(n!) \geq \frac{n}{2}\log(\frac{n}{2})$
$\log(n!) = \Omega(n\hspace{3pt}\log\hspace{3pt}n)$

I don't understand how finding the lower bound of $\log(n!)$ is found by getting the larger half of the sum. Why is that chosen to find $\Omega(n\hspace{3pt}\log \hspace{3pt} n)$? I feel like it's probably something obvious but it's the only thing keeping me from fully grasping the proof. If someone can enlighten me, I would appreciate it!

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? All summands are non-negative, so the whole sum is not less than its part. Also $n/2\le n/2+1\le \dots$, this gives the final estimate. Why is this approach chosen? Because it works.

Comment: It turns out one can "give away" an awful lot in finding a suitable lower bound. This gives constant $1/2$, and in fact one cannot very much better by trying for a better (greater) lower bound.

Comment: This is a very bad way of cross-posting.

Comment: Crossposting is generally frowned upon. If you decide to cross-post anyway, the very least you should to is to clearly indicate that in your post and add the link to the post on the other site. See, for example, [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5088). You can find several other [discussions about crossposting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-posting) on meta.

Answer (score 2):

The same question has already an accepted answer at Computer Science SE:
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/47561/confused-about-proof-that-logn-thetan-log-n

(I am posting this CW answer so that the question does not remain unanswered. I will also add here a link to [post on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) about [cross-posting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-posting).)